# creating groups of a date column of a data frame using a date list with dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I define a following data frame

```
d = as.Date('2015-01-01') + runif(100,0,365)
newData = data.frame('dates' =d, 'num' = c(1:100))
```

newData:

```
     dates      num
1   2015-05-08   1
2   2015-08-18   2
3   2015-06-18   3
4   2015-01-26   4
5   2015-04-04   5
6   2015-01-22   6
7   2015-01-14   7
8   2015-04-21   8
9   2015-07-19   9
10  2015-01-25  10
11  2015-05-15  11
...
```

next I define a date list c as follows

```
a = as.Date('2015-01-01')
b = a + 365
c = seq.Date(a,b,(b-a)/4)
```

c:

```
[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-04-02" "2015-07-02" "2015-10-01" "2016-01-01"
```

Next what I want to achieve is create 5 groups of newData for the condition newData$dates < c[i], where i = 1..5 { this is just an illustration not actual code, I want to use dplyr to achieve this}

Once I have these groups I can pipe them into next piece of my code & for this I wanted to use group_by in dplyr.

Tried out the following command after many iterations

```
result = group_by(newData, new = dates < c)
```

Didn't get the 5 groups I wanted but got the following result:

```
Source: local data frame [100 x 3]
Groups: new [2]

        dates   num   new
       <date> <int> <lgl>
1  2015-05-08     1 FALSE
2  2015-08-18     2 FALSE
3  2015-06-18     3  TRUE
4  2015-01-26     4  TRUE
5  2015-04-04     5  TRUE
6  2015-01-22     6 FALSE
7  2015-01-14     7  TRUE
8  2015-04-21     8  TRUE
9  2015-07-19     9  TRUE
10 2015-01-25    10  TRUE
# ... with 90 more rows
```

On a closer inspection realized the comparison was element by element i.e. first 5 elements of newData$dates were compared with 5 elements of the c list & this continues.
Any way to resolve & get the five groups in a tbl using dplyr? Appreciate the help

Thanks
Param

Comment: Why `i` is from `1` to `4`, not `5`?

Comment: How do you use `i` for the `newData` data frame?

Comment: Oops my bad, i = 1..5 corrected. Further the example in terms of i is just for understanding. Have punched in the actual code

Comment: So which dates in `newData` should compare to which dates in `c`?

Comment: group 1 - newData$dates < c[1], ..., group 5 - newData$dates < c[5]

Comment: you want group 2 to have date c[1] <= st newData$dates < c[2]? Or you want five indicators st group1 = 1 for all observations with date < c[1] ... ?

Comment: group 1:: newData$dates < c[1], group 2::newData$dates < c[2], group 3::newData$dates < c[3], group 4::newData$dates < c[4],group 5 :: newData$dates < c[5]

Comment: And want to use dplyr group_by so that I can pipe it as tbl into next portions of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
result = newData %>% group_by(group1 = dates < c[1]) %>% 
 group_by(group2 = dates < c[2], add = TRUE) %>%  
 group_by(group3 = dates < c[3], add = TRUE) %>% 
 group_by(group4 = dates < c[4], add = TRUE) %>% 
 group_by(group5 = dates < c[5], add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Ok though hard coded this works, what looks good too is the fact that in case of `c[1]` the group is dropped. I changed `c[1]` as `c[1] = c[1] + 90` & got 5 group columns & also this is shown in the output too:

`Source: local data frame [100 x 7]
Groups: group1, group2, group3, group4, group5 [1]`

however when I pass result into a summarise function to count per group, the results don't look right

`result %>% summarise(count = n())` I compared each count element with `which(newData$dates < c[i])`

Comment: I was under the impression that `group_by` creates a single group column, but this is interesting that you can define multiple groups with new column types. @simone do you have any references on this?

Comment: "the results don't look right" : referring to your original data : `length(which(newData$dates < c[3]))  ## 46` , which is the sum of last two rows of `count` in `result %>% summarise(count = n())`

Comment: from `?group_by()`: "add: By default, when add = FALSE, group_by will override existing groups. To instead add to the existing groups, use add = TRUE"

Comment: does that answer your question?

Comment: since I am using `runif` in generating my data no able to reproduce the exact count results. On the current run, `result %>% summarise(count = n())` gives me the following output of counts - `23, 21, 33 & 23`. Whereas the actual numbers are the cumulative i.e., `23, 56, 77 & 100`.  And count for `newData$dates < c[5]` should be indeed 100, am I missing something here?

Comment: Look at '?set.seed()' to get reproducible results

Comment: Ok but are you getting similar results for summarise?

Comment: 23 + 33 = 56, 56 + 21 = 77, 77 + 23 = 100. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes I do see that @simone, I did point it out in my comment too indicating the outputs are cumulative. What I didn't understand was the structure of the output why report it in this way. You mention `23+ 33`, but the order is `23,21,33, & 23 `. Pardon my naivety but wanted to be absolutely sure that when I pipe the next piece correct entries for relevant groups go in

Comment: Maybe that's closer to what you want `lapply(result[,c(3:7)], function(x) sum(x==TRUE))`